# bootstrap hamburger menu not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My hamburger button doesn't work when I click it. I'm using bootstrap and I followed the bootstrap documentation, but it seems that nothing is working. I also put my bootstrap.js and jquery in the order that other posts mention.

Any ideas on what's going on? Are my links in the wrong order or are they not working? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Gloriane Tran's personal website with information about her academic work and projects.">
<meta name="author" content="Gloriane Tran">

<!--JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap Themes-->
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javacsript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Icons-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Stylesheets-->
<link href="/stylesheets/footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/font.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Fonts-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen|Rufina" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Page Title -->
<title>Gloriane Tran | Home</title>
<link href="/stylesheets/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand rufina" href="/">Gloriane Tran</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right rufina">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a newer version of jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you are up to date:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

tested and it works !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand rufina" href="/">Gloriane Tran</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right rufina">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's possible that he's up to date on Bootstrap, in which case he's probably fine with his local copy. I agree that he needs to update jQuery, though!

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I was lost for quite a bit of time. :)